# Simplify shapefiles

Tags: python, shapefile, simplify

I've shapefiles with me and I want to de-code those file and want to build a custom map. Could someone let me know how can I do that with out using Python code.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @srikanthakula! Your question currently doesn't provide enough information and may be flagged (and possibly downvoted). Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/177832/edit) your question to include what you have tried and what code (if any) you have etc.

Comment: What do you mean "de-code"? Do you just want to know how to load them into ArcGIS?

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correct, then you want to make a shapefile?

When you have loaded your base layer map into the chosen GIS software, then you build a map by locking up the layer and editing it with your chosen vector or point. There you also apply attributes.

Eventually see this video: [Https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUnUrTzP2dw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUnUrTzP2dw)

Comment: Hi Michael, I've shapefiles with me and I want to build a custom map for a particular state(Kerala) of Indian using these shapefiles. I don't know how to do it in ArcGIS

Comment: What are your resources of geographical reference? If you have looked at the link, that explains how to make points, lines, polygons and saving them to be a shapefile. - if you have, then i kindly ask you do make a more detailed explanation of what you want to do. For example you can add pictures or videos that might illustrate what you want to achieve.